# How to make notepad++ treat csproj files as XML automatically?

Tags: text-editor, notepad++, file-extension, csproj

I often use notepad++ for editing of the csproj files. And I always need to go to the Language menu and select XML in order to get syntax highlighting.

Is it possible to configure notepad++ to treat csproj files as XML automatically?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Open Settings -> Style Configurator, select "XML" in "Language" list, add "csproj" (without quotes) to "User ext" box.

Comment: No matter how many times I need to do this, I can never remember where.

Answer (score 9):

Edit the file langs.xml in the notepad++ folder.

Change this

```
<Language name="xml" ext="xml xsml xsl xsd kml wsdl" commentLine="" commentStart="&lt;!--" commentEnd="--&gt;">
</Language>
```

by

```
<Language name="xml" ext="xml xsml xsl xsd kml wsdl csproj" commentLine="" commentStart="&lt;!--" commentEnd="--&gt;">
</Language>
```

Comment: close all your files opened with notepad++, then restart notepad++ to make changes to take effect.

Comment: **UPDATE**: in latest version of Notepad++ the file is called "_**langs.model.xml**_"